# How to use customer credit balance without invoice in stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, bubble.io

I want to create a system in bubble.io app with stripe, in which:

1. the customer while purchasing products will pay though their credit balance but the invoice should not generate (or without invoice).
   if it possible, then how? and if not then:
2. customer should transfer money to stripe platform balance and whenever they make a purchase the money should transfer from stripe platform balance to the seller.

any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The customer's [credit balance](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/balance) automatically applies toward the next invoice of the customer. So if you are not using invoices, it won't work. The alternative is to keep track of the customer's balance on your end, and change the amount they need to pay accordingly.
2. If you want the platform account to charge the customer, and then later send the funds to the connected account(s), then you should use [separate charges & transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers).

Comment: but i want customers to first pay to the stripe platform account whenever they want(before purchasing) and then the admin will pay for their purchases. inshort i want to customise the system, but not sure whether this will be proper arrangement for both the stripe and bubble.io  to understand...!!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with bubble, but what you describe is possible with [separate charges & transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers). First the customers pays the platform, the platform keeps track of customers' balances, and later the platform transfer funds to the connected account(s).

Comment: ok. I will try. Thank you for the response